# Making text appear on hover

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a text box appear when I hovered over something different.
*In my code: I want to hover over the h1 block and make the h3 block appear.*

```css
h1.title {
  font-size: 100px;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Orion_Nebula_-_Hubble_2006_mosaic_18000.jpg);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition: 5.6s ease, 3s transform;
}

h1.title:hover {
  background-position: left;
  transform: translateX(150px) /* Where the .ps would appear */
}

.ps {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1 class="title">Random Thing</h1>
  <h3 class="ps">Playing around in HTML!</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the adjacent sibling combinator +:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators

```
h1.title:hover + .ps {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @progysm; it worked!  I would accept your answer but Stack Overflow says I need to wait D:

Comment: Just for future reference, is there a way that I could make the `<h1>` disappear when I hover over it, but the `.ps` appear?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your comment.

Comment: I mean when I hover over one object, make that object disappear and another one appear. It's ok if you don't know, I am just wondering for the future.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, comments in css are made by

`/*  text */`

The answer to your question:

```
h1.title:hover + .ps {
  display: block;
}
```

Don't use visibility styling because when I used it before it didn't work. And display is more common.

Hope this works!

Comment: might be something while in the program I use.  I tried that kind of comment before, and it didn't work.  Maybe I typed it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
h1.title:hover + #ps {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Sometimes I can't use a dot when making code that represents an element with an id.